# Crystal Report : Operation not yet implemented

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, crystal-reports

I am using the .Net 2008 web application with Crystal Report 10.5. I am able to generate the PDF report in Windows 7. But when I run the application on Windows Server 2012, it shows the below issue.

> Error in File
>   C:\Users\sampleUser\AppData\Local\Temp\rptManger{DDEB2C17-C5FD-49C1-B7BF-57F30AB6636C}.rpt:
>   Operation not yet implemented.    at
>   CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ConvertDotNetToErom.ThrowDotNetException(Exception
>   e)    at
>   CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.EromReportSourceBase.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext
>   reqContext)    at
>   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext
>   reqContext)    at
>   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.Export(ExportRequestContext
>   reqContext)    at
>   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.Export()    at
>   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Export()    at
>   SEI.MA_APPS.PortfolioModels.Web.ManagerDetailByBank.GetReport()    at
>   SEI.MA_APPS.PortfolioModels.Web.ManagerDetailByBank.validate()

Answer (score 9):

There is one more solution for this problem.

`Uninstall Update for Microsoft Windows(KB3102429)`

> Control Panel –> Program & Features –> View installed updates and Search
>   for KB3102429, right click and uninstall.

This solved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

One of the reasons for this error can be that one of the fonts used in this report is not installed on your new server. Check if it's installed.

Check this link http://www.crystalreportsbook.com/Forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=1050

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have already checked this. I have a report where we are using only Ariel and Times of Roman which are already installed in Windows 2012 machine.

Comment: If I were I would try do a blank report and export it, if it's works, then I would start to remove parts of the failing report to find what is failing. With this way you will find if this an error on your report or a system error.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have also tried this. I have delete all the fields and now this is a blank report. Still it is showing the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Control Panel –> Program & Features –> View installed updates and Search for KB3102429, right click and uninstall.

Comment: Same problem, this was our fix as well.  One issue we had was an error during the uninstall: "uninstall failed".  After a full reboot of the machine the KB was uninstalled and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 2):

Try using other font other than Times New Roman and Arial. say Calibri.
That worked for me

Comment: I just had to go through 15 reports and change all the Arial to Verdana. Such a PITA and so weird that it would be fonts that are so common that cause the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your support, I got the solution. I opened a report and `Surpress` the fields one by one and found the fields those have `The Times New Roman` font are creating the problem.

Since the font "The Times New Roman" is already installed on the Windows 2012.

Then we copied the font "The Times New Roman" from the local Windows 7 and copied to the Windows Server 2012 and restarted the machine and its working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall Update for Microsoft Windows(KB3102429 and KB3104002)

> Control Panel –> Program & Features –> View installed updates and
>   Search for KB3102429 and KB3104002 right click and uninstall.

Answer (score 1):

mostly the problem is because of fonts in the new version of windows, I find a way by trick, we can use third party app. First we can convert the crystal report to the word document and by **WordToPDF** we cant achieve what we need, although this is not the best practice but it works and I think it is better than changing the fonts or even removing the window's updates. so all you have to do is getting `WordToPDF` from NuGet manager then follow my code:

```
// before executing the code be sure you have a such directory or folder in c drive
 string filePath = @"C:\word2Pdf\";
            string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "wordReport.doc";
            var fileNameAndPath = filePath + fileName;
            initRep.ExportToDisk(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.WordForWindows, fileNameAndPath);
var word2Pdf = new Word2Pdf();
object fromLocation = fileNameAndPath;
            string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
            string changeExtension = fileName.Replace(fileExtension, ".pdf");
            if (fileExtension == ".doc")
            {
                object toLocation = filePath  + changeExtension;
                word2Pdf.InputLocation = fromLocation;
                word2Pdf.OutputLocation = toLocation;
                word2Pdf.Word2PdfCOnversion();
            }
```