# Error in file .... operation not yet implemented

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports, c#-3.0, crystal-reports-2008

This question might look like a copy of [Crystal Report : Operation not yet implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30787669/crystal-report-operation-not-yet-implemented) but the solution didn't did the trick. Getting to the point.

Today, out of nowhere (error was not showing until today) an error started prompting on 3 of my computers where debugging tool is not installed and cannot be installed. The error message is shown below

[image]

This error is generated as soon as i try to generate a PDF file for it but when i try to print the same crystal report it works perfectly.

Platform i am using is **VS2008** and **Crystal Report 2008** on **Windows 8 x64**

**EDIT**

My report uses 3 fonts (Calibri,Arial,Tahoma). I also tried to install all the fonts (456 fonts) from my PC (where no such error is showing) to the other 3 PC's but this error is still persisting.

Please tell me how to get around this error

Comment: remove any non standard fonts from your crystal report.

Comment: i have already edit my question before you mentioned it that i only use these 3 standard fonts in it

Comment: Sometimes doing a re-install does just the trick for cleaning up DLL confusion in the registry. Tech support couldn't fix a bug so I reinstalled VS.NET and it all started working again.

Comment: i read the same comment on the internet and did it but no success

Comment: Just switch your font Times New Roman to 'Georgia' font and try

Comment: @Jignesh.Raj sorry my dear friend there was a mistake in the question there is no "Times In New Roman" font instead it is "Arial"

Comment: I have the same problem with a clients and I had to restore system from a point for an update of windows and it solve my problem, Still not identify the KB update to affect it.  I hope this help :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this help, is the KB3102429 that affect to Crystal Reports, thanks Microsoft for more problems :'(

http://www.iris.co.uk/support/knowledgebase/kb/11478

Sorry for my english im Mexican  "Y fierro pariente"

Comment: man you are awesome it did the trick and don't worry about your English in India everyone kind of speak the same way and by the way how did you came to know about that the error was in the update?

Comment: Because was a general error in a program with crystal reports and I tried with serveral things but without result, and I had a restore system and it solve for a one day, and the next day the client call me again, It was when I deduced it and check the last updates of windows one by one and finally I found it, and I hate a Microsoft again jajajaj

Comment: Link no longer active