# Crystal Report When Exporting to PDF: Operation Not Yet Implemented

Tags: crystal-reports, windows-server-2012

Crystal report is working fine on development machine. But when deployed to server its throwing Exception: Operation Not Yet Implemented.
Moreover its working fine when exported to Excel or Word. This is kind of of strange exception.

I am hosting on shared server so the solution provided in
[Crystal Report : operation Not Yet Implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30787669/crystal-report-operation-not-yet-implemented)
cannot work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also faced same problem, Try using other fonts instead of Times New Roman and Arial.

Comment: I tried Calibri, which worked with a minor problem. Now am using Tahoma and its working fine

Answer (score 0):

check that the server does not have installed Windows Update KB3102429 or KB3078601. They don't play well exporting Crystal to PDF.

Comment: Times New Roman and Arial Fonts were causing problem. i changed it to calibri, it is working now

Answer (score 0):

For Windows Server 2012. Download and Install the VC++ Runtime Files SP1. You will get Crystal reports PDF working very good. Really It worked for me.

Comment: Export to PDF for Crystal Reports works for 2012 Server

Comment: Which version of VC++ Runtime Files? 2005?